# Chrome extension adding event to Google Calendar occurs 'Parse Error'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, calendar

I am writing an offline calendar which can sync with Google Calendar. It can get data from Google Calendar, but can't insert events to Google. Here is my inserting code:

```
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendar_id + '/events';
    var request = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'GData-Version': '3.0',
            'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'
        },
        'body': {
            'start': { 'dateTime': '2012-07-24T07:30:00+08:00'},
            'end': { 'dateTime': '2012-07-24T08:30:00+08:00'},
            'summary': calEvent.title,
            'description': calEvent.body,
            'attendees': [ { 'email': calendar_id}],
            'reminders': {
                'overrides': [ {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 15}]
            }
        }
    };
    oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, function(resp) { console.log(resp) }, request);
```

I have checked several times and searched some related problems, still can't figure out where is wrong. Here is the return errors:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure out where is wrong. The body of the request must be strings.

```
var body = {
'start': { 'dateTime': '2012-07-24T07:30:00+08:00'},
            'end': { 'dateTime': '2012-07-24T08:30:00+08:00'},
            'summary': calEvent.title,
            'description': calEvent.body,
            'attendees': [ { 'email': calendar_id}],
            'reminders': {
                'overrides': [ {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 15}]
            }
        }
```

Then turn the body into strings:

```
body = JSON.stringify(body)
```

Set the request variable:

```
request = {
    .....
    'body': body
    .....
}
```